# SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetStringValue(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName + ".GlogalVariableKey") not getting vaues

Tags: kentico

Kentico, Have developed code, but due to some reason the code is not working in QC environment. want to connect kentico cms of QC environment.How to debug the c# code using QC Kentico as target Kentico. and setting. please suggest here.

like `SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetStringValue(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName + ".GlobalVariableName")`
not getting current value from cms. its getting old_values. How to make get latest values immediately upon changing the values

thanks you.

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: kentico version 12

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to caching. You can attempt to clear the cache before you retrieve the setting value but it will slow the system down.

Also I'd look at what you're doing with the system settings. Are you attempting to save a value and then get that new value right away or simply retrieve the value at any time? Typically with settings keys, they don't change very often.  In the event they are updated in the UI, you need to clear the cache to see those updates immediately.

Comment: Again the same kind of issues. like for smart forms have added new two fields/controls(type radiobutton) in developmnet and sync with QC in staging step. here the newly added two fields are not showing in QC but in versions comparission showing those two fields. but not showing in formBuilders. what to do. it seems like cache. but to clear the cache.?

Comment: You're talking about forms and field controls now.  How are these related to getting system settings in C#?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the fact that you Kentico  MVC instance doesn't know about the change that you made in the admin interface. Make sure that web farms are enabled. Here is the [topic on that](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/mvc-cache-dependency-via-web-farm)

Answer (score 0):

On your MVC instance under a controller or any other method, you could use:

```
CacheHelper.ClearCache();
```

It will help you to clear the cache on the MVC project and retrieve the latest value of a setting key.